# Explanation on how to draw a straight line in Raphael.js

Tags: svg, raphael

I would like some help on the path constructor in Raphael. Im not sure how to draw a straight line from one point to another. 
I have

```
var line = paper.path(M 100 0 1 0 30 100)
```

I want to draw a line from point1 (100 0) to point2 (30 100)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
var line = paper.path( "M100,0 L30,100" );
```

You can also build your paths out of arrays, which is really useful in some circumstances.

```
var line = paper.path( ["M", 100, 0, "L", 30, 100 ] );
```

Comment: M = "move to" and L = "line to".  Path syntax is entirely directive based.  If you want the complete list of commands, check out the w3c spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can use relative versions of virtually every directive -- so "M100,0 L30,100" and "M100,0 l-70,100" will produce the same output.